# get value of element which attached to radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button, label

How can I get the value of `.coefficient` when I choose a radio in pair of radio buttons using jQuery?

```
<label class="bet-team-box" for="radio-1">
    <input class="bet-main-input" id="radio-1" name="group1" type="radio">
    <span class="fake-label">
        <span class="team">
            Midnight Sun Esports
        </span>
        <span class="img-box">
            <img src="images/logo-team-04.png" alt="image description" width="20" height="20" />
        </span>
        <span class="coefficient">
            12.43
        </span>
    </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to get the parent `label` element, then `find()` to get the `coefficient`. Try this:

```
$('.bet-main-input').change(function() {
    var coefficient = $(this).closest('label').find('.coefficient').text();
    // use variable here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the  optimal way but you can find it like this.

```
 $("#radio-1").click(function()
 {
   $($($(this).siblings()[0]).children('span.coefficient')).text();
});
```